# Using a CountDownTimer to display a toast until button is pressed

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have an activity that starts after a certain time. Once this activity starts, the user is supposed to press a button that starts a new timer.

However, if the user does not press the button I want a toast to be displayed every 5 seconds until the button is pressed.

I'm trying to use a CountDownTimer. Here is the basics of the code I have so far:

I have no errors but no toasts are being displayed at the moment. Is it ok to have the MyCount class inside the BreakActivity class (if i put it outside I get an error).

Any help in getting this sorted will be greatly appreciated!

```
public class BreakActivity extends Activity {

Button startBreakButton; // button to start the break timer
Boolean clicked= false;
CountDownTimer counter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.breakscreen); // sets layout to breakscreen.xml

    MyCount counter;
    counter=new MyCount(5000,1000);
    counter.start();

  startBreakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBreakButton);
    startBreakButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

  View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() { 

 clicked=true;
 //other listener code
 };

 public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      if(clicked=false){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TAKE A BREAK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        counter= new MyCount(5000,1000);
     counter.start();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long s1 = millisUntilFinished;

    }
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change :

```
 if(clicked=false)
```

to

```
 if(clicked==false)
```